# How to display accounts of a user in which he is a account team member in alookup field?

Tags: account, lookup-filter, account-teams

I have a custom lookup field which is related to account. I want to select only the accounts that I am a team member of. Those accounts have to be shown how to give this filter?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You've added the `lookup-filter` tag; have you tried a Lookup Filter or a Validation Rule?